# embedded c code and unit tests without cross compile

Tags: c, eclipse, unit-testing, cross-compiling, stm32

i am starting to learn unit testing. I use unity and it works well with mingw in eclipse on windows. I use different configurations for debug, release and tests. This works well with the cdt-plugin.

But my goal is to unit test my embedded code for an stm. So i use arm-gcc with the arm-gcc eclipse plugin. I planned to have a configuration for compiling the debug and release code for the target and a configuration using mingw to compile and excute the tests on the pc (just the hardware independet parts).

With the eclipse plugin, i cannot compile code that is not using the arm-gcc.

Is there a way, to have one project with configurations and support for the embedded target and the pc?

Thanks

Comment: It was much easier than expected. I added a new configuration to my arm gcc project. This configuration uses the MinGW Toolchain. And additionaly, i created a new main file, that executes the tests. For all configurations i had to choose, which folders should be executed (for tests i had to exclude the main file folder and my hardware depended files folder). So i could leave the makefile out of focus. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above you need a makefile pointing at two different targets with different compiler options depending on the target.

You will need to ensure portability in your code.

I have accomplished this most often using CMake and outlining different compiler paths and linker flags for unit tests versus the target. This way I can also easily link in any unit test libraries while keeping them external to my target. In the end CMake produces a Makefile but I'm not spending time worrying about make syntax which while I can read often seems like voodoo.

Doing this entirely within a single Eclipse project is possible. You need to configure your project for multiple targets with different compilers used for each and will require some coaxing to get eclipse to behave.

If you're goal is to do it entirely within Eclipse I suggest reading [this](http://tinyguides.blogspot.ru/2013/04/multiple-binaries-in-single-eclipse-cdt.html) as a primer.

If you want to go the other route, here is a [CMake primer](https://ecrafter.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/cmake-primer-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Makefile.

But I guess NEON assemblies are a bigger issue.

Using intrinsics instead is at least open to the possibility to link to a simulator library, and there are indeed a lot of such libraries written in standard C that allow code with intrinsics to be portable.

However the poor performance of GCC Neon intrinsics forces a lot of people to sacrifice portability for performance.

If your code unfortunately contains assembly, you won't be able to even compile the code before translating assemblies back to standard C.

Comment: Inline assembly doesn't have to be such a hard ship if you plan for it accordingly. You treat it essentially the same way as you would a memory mapped peripheral. Build your test harness around it when you are on target and mock it with C on host. For memory mapped peripherals, accessing them using inline functions makes them much easier to mock. But if you have to go through and track down every time you do a bitwise operation on some symbol that corresponds to a memory mapped peripheral and replace it with a call to an inline function it could be very tedious on a large code base.